# Google Font fetching is too slow

Tags: material-ui, google-font-api

I'm building a web app using react and material UI. I use the roboto font-family and fetch it this way in my index.html file:

```
<link
        rel="preload"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap"
        as="style"
/>
```

I have read online that this is the preferred way of fetching the fonts to improve performance. However, when I fetch the SPA from google Pagespeed Insight, I get bad results for mobile devices and a recommendation to prefetch some resources. Among these resources, I find:

```
…media/roboto-latin-500.020c97dc.woff2
…media/roboto-latin-400.479970ff.woff2
…media/roboto-latin-300.ef7c6637.woff2
```

But I thought that these assets were included in my previous call.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your CSS file and how it is referencing the fonts? It looks like the URL you have in the HTML may be different than the one referenced in your CSS file. This may be causing the issue and the recommendation from PageSpeed tool.

Comment: I'm using material-ui. I think the css styling happens under the hood, as I can't find any explicit references to the files in my code.